# iOS build error from visual studio in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio

Here I am working on app which is developing in angularjs, at the time of iOS build. I am geating error.

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>   Error  Error: Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/inativetech/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/890/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,MedintuCorporate.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,MedintuCorporate,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/inativetech/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/890/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/inativetech/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/890/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch - 1  Corporate  1

Here Corporate is the my app name..